# Problem Powershell setting screen brightness

Tags: powershell, screen, brightness

I am setting the screen brightness to 50% in Powershell with this command

`(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,50)`

However, when I check the brightness in the notification pane, it remains the same.
[image]

Further, I do not see any change in the brightness of the screen. Could someone please tell me if this is how the software is supposed to work? Is this normal?
Am I missing something?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you checked the return value from ```WmiSetBrightness```? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmicoreprov/wmisetbrightness-method-in-class-wmimonitorbrightnessmethods#return-value for expected result and error codes. Also, do you have multiple monitors, because it looks like you set it individually for each…

Comment: testing on Win11 it works exactly like expected.

Comment: @mclayton comment seems to go in the right direction.

`(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,50)
        Get-Ciminstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightness`
This commands do not return the brightness to 50% (even if I set it so before). How can I set it for different monitors?

Comment: Any hint? @mclayton

Comment: Any hint? @FalcoAlexander

Comment: Update on this. Sometimes, it seems to work so other times no. It is somewhat confusing.